# How to Remove Space between Widget?

Tags: qt, layout

How to remove the space between widgets when applying a layout.

In Qt, if I apply any layout to a widget like, QBoxLayout or QGridlayout, it automatically creates space between widgets. I need to remove the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for [QLayout::setSpacing()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) function.